# angular async for observable how to show fields?

Tags: angular

$app is Obseravable,

When I use:

```
email::::: {{ app$ | async }}
```

I get on screen:

```
email::::: [object Object]
```

But if I use:

```
email::::: {{ app$.email | async }}
```

I get on screen:

```
email:::::
```

Together with the error on console:

```
MyComponent.html:3 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'true' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4232)
    at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe._selectStrategy (common.js:4839)
    at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe._subscribe (common.js:4829)
    at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe.transform (common.js:4811)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (SocialLoginComponent.html:3)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11914)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11307)
    at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11490)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11313)
```

How can I print `app$.email` with the async modifier?

Comment: have you subscribed to `app$` in your code? can you show the observable code?

Comment: sharing my component.ts updating the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wait for the emission of the observable using the async pipe. Once it emits then you have access to the object with the email property on it. By wrapping the subscribe in parentheses you can access the email property like so:

```html
{{ (app$ | async).email }}
```